# Split an array into slices, with groupings

Tags: arrays, ruby, enumerable

I've got some Ruby code here, that works, but I'm certain I'm not doing it as efficiently as I can.

I have an Array of Objects, along this line:

```
[
    { name: "foo1", location: "new york" },
    { name: "foo2", location: "new york" },
    { name: "foo3", location: "new york" },
    { name: "bar1", location: "new york" },
    { name: "bar2", location: "new york" },
    { name: "bar3", location: "new york" },
    { name: "baz1", location: "chicago" },
    { name: "baz2", location: "chicago" },
    { name: "baz3", location: "chicago" },
    { name: "quux1", location: "chicago" },
    { name: "quux2", location: "chicago" },
    { name: "quux3", location: "chicago" }
]
```

I want to create some number of groups - say 3 - where each group contains a semi-equal amount of items, but interspersed by `location`.

I tried something like this:

```
group_size = 3
groups = []

group_size.times do
    groups.push([])
end

i = 0
objects.each do |object|
    groups[i].push(object)
    if i < (group_size - 1)
        i += 1
    else
        i = 0
    end
end
```

This returns a `groups` object, that looks like:

```
[
    [{:name=>"foo1", :location=>"new york"},
     {:name=>"bar1", :location=>"new york"},
     {:name=>"baz1", :location=>"chicago"},
     {:name=>"quux1", :location=>"chicago"}],
    [{:name=>"foo2", :location=>"new york"},
     {:name=>"bar2", :location=>"new york"},
     {:name=>"baz2", :location=>"chicago"},
     {:name=>"quux2", :location=>"chicago"}],
    [{:name=>"foo3", :location=>"new york"},
     {:name=>"bar3", :location=>"new york"},
     {:name=>"baz3", :location=>"chicago"},
     {:name=>"quux3", :location=>"chicago"}]
]
```

So you can see there's a couple of objects from each location in each grouping.

I played around with `each_slice()` and `group_by()`, even tried to use `inject([])` - but I couldn't figure out a more elegant method to do this.

I'm hoping it's something that I'm overlooking - and I need to account for more `location`s and a non-even number of Objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this bookkeeping with `i` is usually a sign there should be something better. I came up with:

```
ar =[
    { name: "foo1", location: "new york" },
    { name: "foo2", location: "new york" },
    { name: "foo3", location: "new york" },
    { name: "bar1", location: "new york" },
    { name: "bar2", location: "new york" },
    { name: "bar3", location: "new york" },
    { name: "baz1", location: "chicago" },
    { name: "baz2", location: "chicago" },
    { name: "baz3", location: "chicago" },
    { name: "quux1", location: "chicago" },
    { name: "quux2", location: "chicago" },
    { name: "quux3", location: "chicago" }
]

# next line handles unsorted arrays, irrelevant with this data 
ar = ar.sort_by{|h| h[:location]}

num_groups = 3
groups     = Array.new(num_groups){[]}
wheel      = groups.cycle
ar.each{|h| wheel.next << h}

# done.
p groups
# => [[{:name=>"baz1", :location=>"chicago"}, {:name=>"quux1", :location=>"chicago"}, {:name=>"foo1", :location=>"new york"}, ...]
```

because I like the [cycle](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-cycle) method.

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't been familiar with `.cycle` and this made me research it a bit more and I think it matches the problem quite well.

Comment: I too am fond of `cycle`. I often use it in a block instead of `each_with_index`. "wheel" is a great name for the enumerator.

Answer (score 3):

`a.each_slice(group_size).to_a.transpose`

Will work given that your data is accurately portrayed in the example. If it is not please supply accurate data so that we can answer the question more appropriately.

e.g.

```
a= [
    { name: "foo1", location: "new york" },
    { name: "foo2", location: "new york" },
    { name: "foo3", location: "new york" },
    { name: "bar1", location: "new york" },
    { name: "bar2", location: "new york" },
    { name: "bar3", location: "new york" },
    { name: "baz1", location: "chicago" },
    { name: "baz2", location: "chicago" },
    { name: "baz3", location: "chicago" },
    { name: "quux1", location: "chicago" },
    { name: "quux2", location: "chicago" },
    { name: "quux3", location: "chicago" }
]
group_size = 3
a.each_slice(group_size).to_a.transpose
#=> [
     [
      {:name=>"foo1", :location=>"new york"},
      {:name=>"bar1", :location=>"new york"},
      {:name=>"baz1", :location=>"chicago"},
      {:name=>"quux1", :location=>"chicago"}
    ],
    [
      {:name=>"foo2", :location=>"new york"},
      {:name=>"bar2", :location=>"new york"},
      {:name=>"baz2", :location=>"chicago"},
      {:name=>"quux2", :location=>"chicago"}
    ],
    [
      {:name=>"foo3", :location=>"new york"},
      {:name=>"bar3", :location=>"new york"},
      {:name=>"baz3", :location=>"chicago"},
      {:name=>"quux3", :location=>"chicago"}
    ]
  ]
```

`each_slice` 3 will turn this into 4 equal groups (numbered 1,2,3) in your example. `transpose` will then turn these 4 groups into 3 groups of 4.

If the locations are not necessarily in order you can add sorting to the front of the method chain

```
a.sort_by { |h| h[:location]  }.each_slice(group_size).to_a.transpose
```

**Update**

It was pointed out that an uneven number of arguments for `transpose` will raise. My first though was to go with @CarySwoveland's approach but since he already posted it I came up with something a little different

```
class Array
  def indifferent_transpose
    arr = self.map(&:dup)
    max = arr.map(&:size).max
    arr.each {|a| a.push(*([nil] * (max - a.size)))}
    arr.transpose.map(&:compact)
  end
end
```

then you can still use the same methodology

```
a << {name: "foobar1", location: "taiwan" }
a.each_slice(group_size).to_a.indifferent_transpose
#=> [[{:name=>"foo1", :location=>"new york"},
      {:name=>"bar1", :location=>"new york"},
      {:name=>"baz1", :location=>"chicago"},
      {:name=>"quux1", :location=>"chicago"},
      #note the extras values will be placed in the group arrays in order 
      {:name=>"foobar4", :location=>"taiwan"}], 
    [{:name=>"foo2", :location=>"new york"},
      {:name=>"bar2", :location=>"new york"},
      {:name=>"baz2", :location=>"chicago"},
      {:name=>"quux2", :location=>"chicago"}],
    [{:name=>"foo3", :location=>"new york"},
      {:name=>"bar3", :location=>"new york"},
      {:name=>"baz3", :location=>"chicago"},
      {:name=>"quux3", :location=>"chicago"}]]
```

Comment: I think `.transpose` will bail if there's not an even number of elements - I think I mentioned that in the last line of my question.

Comment: @MikeFiedler you are correct and I would post updated code but CarySwoveland posted the exact methodology I would have gone with so there is no point to this although I will update this just so that is is correct but far less clean

Comment: @MikeFiedler I have updated my answer to suit you needs. I chose to monkey patch but this could be implemented outside of `Array` just as easily.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time! I ended up using the `cycle` method - as it makes most sense to someone looking at the code for the first time.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to do it.

**Code**

```
def group_em(a, ngroups)
  a.each_with_index.with_object(Array.new(ngroups) {[]}) {|(e,i),arr|
    arr[i%ngroups] << e}
end
```

**Example**

```
a = [
    { name: "foo1",  location: "new york" },
    { name: "foo2",  location: "new york" },
    { name: "foo3",  location: "new york" },
    { name: "bar1",  location: "new york" },
    { name: "bar2",  location: "new york" },
    { name: "bar3",  location: "new york" },
    { name: "baz1",  location: "chicago"  },
    { name: "baz2",  location: "chicago"  },
    { name: "baz3",  location: "chicago"  },
    { name: "quux1", location: "chicago"  },
    { name: "quux2", location: "chicago"  }
]
```

Note that I've omitted the last element of `a` from the question in order for `a` to have an odd number of elements.

```
group_em(a,3)
  #=> [[{:name=>"foo1",  :location=>"new york"},
  #     {:name=>"bar1",  :location=>"new york"},
  #     {:name=>"baz1",  :location=>"chicago" },
  #     {:name=>"quux1", :location=>"chicago" }],
  #    [{:name=>"foo2",  :location=>"new york"},
  #     {:name=>"bar2",  :location=>"new york"},
  #     {:name=>"baz2",  :location=>"chicago" },
  #     {:name=>"quux2", :location=>"chicago" }],
  #    [{:name=>"foo3",  :location=>"new york"},
  #     {:name=>"bar3",  :location=>"new york"},
  #     {:name=>"baz3",  :location=>"chicago" }]]
```

Comment: excellent answer as soon as the OP pointed out that `transpose` will raise for uneven number of objects this is the exact solution that came to mind.

Comment: This is also a good method - but I suspect while the `cycle` method may be unfamiliar to some, I accepted that answer, as the mental construct is simpler to parse. Thanks for taking a second pass at this!

Comment: I agree with your choice, as I would have have used `cycle` had @steenslag not already done so.